byrow() to skip based on other column for optimization
I have ID data in col A9:A where all the matrix data placed in col AA9:AL.
In cell B9 I put this code. I want to get the right most column number for every row which is not empty for - every ID/row.
I use this code :
=byrow( AA9:AL ,lambda( r ,  ifna( column(indirect( ADDRESS(1, MAX(FILTER(COLUMN(r), r<> "")), 4) ))  ,) ))

This works perfectly as I want. But I'm just thinking if I have 3000 row and I only have not many ID data and matrix in the beginning ( let say now I have 100 data - but the data is growing up to 3000 or more) then I think the AA9:AL seems to 'waste' the calculation for now.
so I do modification :
=BYROW(AA9:AL, LAMBDA(r, IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(A:A, ROW(r))), "", IFNA(COLUMN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, MAX(FILTER(COLUMN(r), r<> "")), 4))), ""))))

where I tried to process only if A is not empty. I don't see any significant different because I don't have giant data. But If anyone can explain if this modification helps or not ? Maybe the first code is faster ? because the second code , even though it tries to skip the rows where the Col A is empty , It also add another command (if/isblank) to process.
Any thoughts ? or Does anyone have better code ?

So, if you want to run BYROW() only for those ranges of AA9:AL(x) that have data in column A, here (x) means row number based on data in column A then here is one approach.
=byrow(AA9:INDEX(AL:AL,COUNTA(A:A)),lambda(r,ifna(column(indirect(ADDRESS(1,MAX(FILTER(COLUMN(r),r<>"")),4))),)))


Here AA9:INDEX(AL:AL,COUNTA(A:A)) will return a array of values as well cell reference from AA9 to last non empty cell in column AL (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data in Column A). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this post by @TheMaster

Then LAMBDA() will apply you rest of formula function for each row of AA9:ALx.

If you have data till row 100 in A column then full formula will be applied to AA9:AL100 range only. It will no calculate other cells. If you have data till 200 row in A column then full formula will be applied to AA9:AL200 only and so on...


And finally, I assume you may simplify the formula like the following-
=BYROW(AA9:INDEX(AL:AL,COUNTA(A:A)),lambda(r,MAX(INDEX(IF(r<>"",COLUMN(r),"")))))


You can use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
   x,AA9:AL,
   BYROW(INDEX(x,1,1):INDEX(x,MAX(ROW(x)*(""<>x))),
     LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTA(r),MAX(COLUMN(r)*(""<>r)),)))))

